# Property 'navigationController' not found on object of type

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

In order to fix this error :

> 'project.pch' has been modified...

I tried to perform deep clean by pressing `shift+alt+command+k`. Since then I'm getting this error message :

> Property 'navigationController' not found on object of type

[image]

---

I tried several things to resolve it, but no luck yet.

**What I tried :**

> 1. Deleting `/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache`.
> 2. Deleting `/Xcode/DerivedData`.
> 3. Clean Project `Cmd+Shift+K`.
> 4. Deep clean by pressing `Shift+Alt+Cmd+K`.
> 5. Close and Restart the Xcode.

It's not working yet. Can anyone give me any idea on how to resolve this error?

---

***Notes :***

*Project is building/running in Simulator, but unable to build/run on Device.*

*I tried to open the project with other Xcode (Xcode 6.0.1) from my system and it's working.*

Comment: What is `HomeScreen *`?

Comment: @ZaneHelton: It's a `UIViewController`.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to get the `navigationController` property?

Comment: @ZaneHelton: It has nothing to do with the code. Whenever I'm trying to use `navigationController` property of `UIViewController` (say for example, pushing a new screen - `self.navigationController pushView...`), it shows me this error. Have a look at my **Note**, it's working on simulator.

Comment: Please in .h class is there import `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` or not?

Comment: @NitinGohel: Yes, tried.. not working !!

Comment: please attach your implementation of navigation control code with you question so we can identify what is wrong.

Comment: @NitinGohel: As I mentioned in my note, it's working with `Xcode 6.0.1`, there shouldn't be any issue at code side.

Comment: This is the same Problem i am having right now, ! please do provide the answer if you , 
In my case im getting this error on xcode 6.3, but when i run it on xcode 6 its working wonder what may be the cause !